# Overfitting in convolutional neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I was applying CNN for classification of hand gestures I have 10 gestures and 100 images for each gestures. Model constructed by me was giving accuracy around 97% on training data, and I got 89% accuracy in testing data. Can I say that my model is overfitted or is it acceptable to have such accuracy graph(shown below)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add more data to training set**

When you have a large amount of data(all kinds of instances) in your training set, it is good to create an overfitting model.

Example: Let's say you want to detect just one gesture say 'thumbs-up'(Binary classification problem) and you have created your positive training set with around 1000 images where images are rotated, translated, scaled, different colors, different angles, viewpoint varied, back-ground cluttered...etc. And if your training accuracy is 99%, your test accuracy will also be somewhere close.

Because our training set is big enough to cover all instances of the positive class, so even if the model is overfitted, it will perform well with the test set as the instances in the test set will only be a slight variation to that of the instances in the training set.

In your case, your model is good but if you can add some more data, you will get even better accuracy.

**What kind of data to add?**

Manually go through the test samples which the model got wrong and check for patterns if you can figure out what kind of samples are going wrong, you can add such kind to your training set and re-train again.